# I want to display the post excerpt with date and title

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the excerpt of 2 posts with title and post-date, the code is done but it is showing the date only for one post.

Here Is The Code.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="reel-focus-blog wow slideInRight animated">
  <h1>Reel Focus Blog</h1>
   <?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2' );
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> 
     the_post(); ?>
      <div class="reel-focus-blog-box">
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <p class="datetime"><i><?php the_date();?></i></p>
       <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
       <a class="read-more" href="">Read More</a></>
  </div>

  <?php
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with

> get_the_date()

```
// The Args
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
<div class="reel-focus-blog-box">
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <p class="datetime"><i><?php echo get_the_date();?></i></p>
       <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
       <a class="read-more" href="">Read More</a></>
  </div>
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```